Twilio Phone Number Regulations - Not able to assign address to a Bundle
I am following this guide to create bundles using their Rest API.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/regulatory/getting-started/create-new-bundle-public-rest-apis
After creating bundle and assign end user and supporting document, when i run an evaluation on the bundle, it says address sid is missing.
How to assign the address to the bundle then?
I get this error when I try to assign it using their API:
[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: attempting to add invalid object type to bundle

